# wp get_posts limited to 10 results

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a very rare behaviour on my get_posts() in my wp application. This query never returns more than 10 posts no matter what I set my 'numberposts' option to. Using var_dump() I have confirmed this is the case.

```
            $ledningen_posts = get_posts(array(
                'numberposts' => 99,
                'post_type' => 'ledning',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'suppress_filters' => '0'
            ));
```

Comment: Set `posts_per_page=-1` in get_posts

Comment: Yes check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts u just set posts_per_page=-1 to have all data.

Comment: Yes I tried that (actually numberposts and posts_per_page are the same, according to that link you posted). I only changed it to 99 to try something different when -1 didn't work anymore...

Comment: Hmm I think in the newer version its 'nopaging' => true , try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in the new version its `'nopaging' => true` use this and this should work !!

Answer (score 0):

Set `posts_per_page=-1` in get_posts.

```
$ledningen_posts = get_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'ledning',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'suppress_filters' => '0'
            ));
```

See the section **Show all attachments** in [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

As per **Abhik Chakraborty** answer:

update: `'nopaging' => true` for newer versions.